# How to install Metasploit and Armitage

Tags: 16.04, metasploit

I want to install metasploit and armitage on my ubuntu 16.04 LTS laptop running kernel 4.6

I've read blogs and posts on how to install it but the problem is is that they are outdated. The packages are not there anymore and or the commands dont work.

If anyone can give me an updated tutorial on how to install it that would be great. I also think other users that see this post and want to install it will also be thankful. Thanks.

Comment: It's not what you're asking for, but you might consider installing Kali Linux in a VM. It contains all the pen-testing tools you could possibly want.

Comment: Yeah I want too but my laptop has like 2GB ram.

Comment: Here's another good tutorial.
http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/

Answer (score 10):

Here is a blog post (untested but states it works for 16.04): http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/

**OR**

Install metasploit you can use automated installer:

**64 Bit:**

```
wget https://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run && wget https://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run.sha1 && echo $(cat metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run.sha1)'  'metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run > metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run.sha1 && shasum -c metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run.sha1 && chmod +x ./metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run && sudo ./metasploit-latest-linux-x64-installer.run
```

(**for 32bit version, same command but remove '-x64'** from the filename/url)

## Note

This should be ran on a virtual machine, dont ignore ssl errors/hash checksums (both are checked using the above script to ensure files being downloaded are from metasploit.com).

if wget failed makes sure you are using wget-ssl.

Comment: works, yes. But please, never directly run anything without confirming its contents, especially not as root..

Comment: @SaAtomic, it should always be run from a VM anyway, therefore root/normal user is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Care to explain why it should be run from a VM anyways? I don't see it that way.

Comment: 1. Often analysing apps/code from untrusted sources
2. Snapshots
3. Separation of data and other resources
4. More control over data being exposed

The list goes on... unless you only use the machine for pentesting (in which case you would use kali most likely not ubuntu anyways)... then why would you not want to seperate it.

Comment: Simple answer of why to use a VM:  To prevent damaging your own system.

Answer (score -1):

You can download the free version of Metasploit directly from their website: http://www.rapid7.com/products/metasploit/editions.jsp

Alternatively, install Katoolin from GitHub. This is a script that lets you install all the tools provided in Kali Linux. It has a very simple and good user guide and there are also many YouTube videos explaining its use.

https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin

Comment: Katoolin doesn't work with Ubuntu Xenial (16.04 LTS).

Comment: rapid7.com is definitely not Metasploit's website.

Comment: @MladenB. please be careful when making claims. The download link from https://www.metasploit.com/ points to https://www.rapid7.com/products/metasploit/download/pro/, metasploit is made by Rapid7.

Comment: I sincerely apologize. My mistake. I just checked thoroughly and it appears I was wrong. The link looked alike the rapidshare of some sort...